# Reset root password in Cisco IOS XRv 9000 Router

Tags: cisco, router

Can someone help me with change root password in Cisco IOS XRv 9000 Router? 
I can log in as root. I'm telnetting to access the console.

Comment: you can do it in roman mode

Comment: how do i get in to rommon mode ? im telnetting  to access the console

Comment: https://www.vology.com/cisco-2800-password-recovery-2801-2811-2821-2851/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already logged in as root, you can use these commands:

```
configure
username <root-user-name>
secret <mynewpassword>
commit
```